# I am trying to parse an xml file on my desktop. I am getting an error

Tags: android

Parse code is :

```
private UrlList parseUrl(URL url) {
    URL SourceUrl = null;
    SourceUrl = url;

    try {
        /** Handling XML */
        SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();
        XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader();
        /** Create handler to handle XML Tags ( extends DefaultHandler ) */
        XMLParser myXmlParser = new XMLParser();
        xr.setContentHandler(myXmlParser);
        xr.parse(new InputSource(SourceUrl.openStream()));

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(" XMLParsing error is : " + e);
    }

    urlList = XMLParser.urlList;
    return urlList;
}// end of parseurl
```

The url that iam giving is
sourceUrl = new URL("file://C:/Users/raghu/Desktop/aero/products.xml");
similarly , i have the resources path also in the same manner

```
file://C:/Users/raghu/Desktop/aero/"resource sub folders"
```

I am getting the following error

```
     D/dalvikvm(  118): GC_EXPLICIT freed 80K, 52% free 2864K/5895K, external 2155K/2537K, paused 82ms
W/System.err( 1078): java.io.IOException: Unable to connect to server: null
W/System.err( 1078):    at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.ftp.FtpURLConnection.connect(FtpURLConnection.java:203)
W/System.err( 1078):    at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.ftp.FtpURLConnection.getInputStream(FtpURLConnection.java:300)
W/System.err( 1078):    at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:645)
W/System.err( 1078):    at com.omkarsoft.ImagePortofolio.ImagePortofolio.parseUrl(ImagePortofolio.java:178)
W/System.err( 1078):    at com.omkarsoft.ImagePortofolio.ImagePortofolio.onCreate(ImagePortofolio.java:76)
W/System.err( 1078):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
W/System.err( 1078):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
W/System.err( 1078):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
W/System.err( 1078):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
W/System.err( 1078):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
W/System.err( 1078):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
W/System.err( 1078):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
W/System.err( 1078):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
W/System.err( 1078):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
W/System.err( 1078):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
W/System.err( 1078):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
W/System.err( 1078):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
```

Comment: Try to this xml store in Asset & try to parse & One thing that u give path "C:/..."may be not properway

Answer (score 2):

You will need to push the file into the Android emulator file system. Eg.

```
adb push C:/Users/raghu/Desktop/aero/products.xml /sdcard/products.xml
```

and use the latter path.

Comment: you can't access files from the desktop from within your emulator. Therefore you need to push whatever files you want to use onto the sdcard (or phone memory).

Comment: IS there no way of doing the above thing ? If not can u tell me how to push the resources into sdcard and give the path to resources in the xml file and the path of the xml file itself in the application?

Comment: I don't understand your last question (in the comment above) properly. But the `adb push` is how you push files into sdcard. Similarly, other resources can be pushed. Alternatively, you can use the DDMS->'File Explorer' tool.

Comment: Sorry for making it hard for u to understand ? i have a folder aero , it contains the xml file and other folders containing images. I have to change the the paths to these files in the xml. so , what path should i give to these images in the xml file. and also , what is the path of the xml file in the sdcard.

Comment: Besides keeping your files as part of your apk (see [Application Resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/index.html)), you can store it anywhere that is accessible by your application. I would suggest you read up on [Data Storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html), especially the parts on Internal and External Storage. Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for ur time, but i am trying to do it the way i described

Comment: OK. Once you find the answer, please share it here.